# Нужно ли добавлять медиа-запрос, если ширина экрана <= 260px?

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Недавно начал практиковаться в медиа-запросах. Нужно ли добавлять медиа-запрос, если ширина экрана <= 260px?
Существуют ли вообще устройства с таким разрешением?
[image: Макет]

Comment: Калькуляторы разве что. 320 - разумный нижний предел.

Comment: Смысл имеется, ведь большинство телефонов Hi-DPI соответсвенно контент увеличивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит делать на `<= 260px` - по моему опыту лучше сделать `@media and screen(max-width: 360px)` - этого будет достаточно. Количество Устройств с разрешением меньше 260px очень мало, а данный медиа запрос с адаптацией каждого элемента займет много ресурсов в *css*